# How to display time 'just now' '1 minute ago' '1 hour ago' respectively

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I working on an worldwide app, the functionality is I need to display the posted time as 'Just now','1 minute ago' '1 hour ago' respectively. I sending the date and time while creating post and send to webservice.And I retrieving the same date time for each post which I need to show on each post with relative time(just now,1 hour,1 week respectively).I'm getting the actual date from webservice as
"created_date" = "2015-01-29 06: 33: 02";
But while I parsing to Nsdate format it returns date as
"2015-01-29 01:03:02 +0000"
 This is the code for date and time to send it server.

```
 NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"DateFormatter%@",[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

The below code I used to format string to date.

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

 dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[value valueForKey:@"created_date"]];
  NSLog(@"Output :%@",date);
```

How to find the actual time elapsed for post shared.I'm new to objective C.I'm not sure What I doing wrong.Please anybody help me fix it out.

Comment: Are you in India? Since there is 5:30 difference between `created_date` and your parsed date, I speculate that these two times are in face the same time, just in different parts of the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are two questions here.

The first one is about natural language date formatting, and I think you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809899/how-can-i-format-a-date-in-objective-c-similar-to-the-jquery-timeago-library/8342881#8342881) relevant.

The second question looks like you're having some confusion about time zones. NSDate is going to parse your date assuming GMT absent any indication of offset or ICU time zone specification. Then when you print it back out, it is likely using your machine's current locale to format the date on output. You should read up on NSDate and NSDateFormatter's handling of time zones.

When sending the date to the server as a string, you should format it like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// Special, agnostic locale
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

// GMT
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

// ISO 8601
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];

NSLog(@"DateFormatter%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,Is there any way to get actual time without date formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... NSDateFormatter can be configured with a locale, a time zone, and a format string, and therefore should be perfectly able to display just the time portion of an NSDate, while correctly accounting for a specific time zone.

Comment: Sorry,let me explain,If I posted something it shows as I'm posted just now.If i posted something 2 hours ago ,it should say 2hours ago.I getting posted date as string from webservice.I don't how to convert to local time from posted time.

Comment: OK, I understand the question, and NSDateFormatter is still the answer. You may have to jump through some hoops depending on how the server stores dates (i.e. is the server giving you dates in GMT? Or in some other time zone?) Canonically, NSDates are stored as a moment in time, relative to GMT, so you need to convert whatever the server gives you to GMT when parsing the server response into an NSDate.

Comment: Instead of getting the server time , I send the time from device along with the post webservice parameter.So I'm getting the same time which I send to them for each post with created time.

Comment: You should probably convert the time to GMT *before* sending it to the server.

Comment: Yeah. When you format the date to a string that you send to the server, you should explicitly set the time zone on the NSDateFormatter to GMT and the locale to en_US_POSIX.

Comment: Added code to show how to do this to my answer. A good post that explains this well is here: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-2/

Comment: Ok,let me try with this

Comment: I used this code now to display time         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
        
        NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[value valueForKey:@"created_date"]];
        NSLog(@"myDate%@", myDate);
        
        
        NSString *string = [myDate timeAgo];
    
    cell.date.text = string;

Comment: But It gives time 2015-01-29 10:55:20 +0000 Instead of 2015-01-29 09:55:20 +0000

Comment: Set the time zone on the formatter, like in the sample code I provided.